# animating time series scatterplot - showing timeline

Tags: tableau-api

I animated a scatterplot of two variables over time using the pages tool in Tableau.

The x-axis is GDP per capita and y-axis is CO2 per capita.

I want to also show the timeline (years) along the bottom of the chart as the user moves through the pages over time. Is this possible in Tableau?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like the example below then just build a few sheets and apply the date to the pages shelf of each sheet. After that, add the sheets to a dashboard and make sure to show the page control for each sheet that you want to animate (click on the little triangle in the top right of the container on the dashboard).

[image]